# How to prove that if $7n - 5$ is odd, then $n$ is even?

Tags: logic

How to prove that

If $7n - 5$ is odd, then $n$ is even?

Comment: If $n$ were odd, $7n-5$ would be even.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio why?

Comment: $$\text{odd}\cdot\text{odd}-\text{odd} = \text{odd}-\text{odd} = \text{even}$$

Comment: First define what is even and what is odd. Secondly, ask yourself if those definitions are objective, and always true independent of human mind. If yes continue if no go to END. If yes, ask yourself if 5 is odd, if yes, ask yourself if 7n is even, if yes ask yourself if 7 is odd, if yes, then what is n, in the end.

Comment: What is your (formal) definition of even and of odd? If you want an answer for such a "small" result, it would be useful to know the exact definitions you have.

Comment: @user549963 Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3):

Suppose by way of contradiction that $n$ were odd. Then $7n$ is odd so $7n-5$ is even. Thus, $n$ must be even.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this modulo $2$. If $7n-5=1$, then $n=7n=5+1=0$ over $\mathbb{Z}/2$.